# Многоточие в сочетании с несколькими восклицательными знаками

Tags: пунктуация, многоточие

Есть предложения, где речь прерывается и постепенно усиливается, сначала одним восклицательным знаком, потом двумя и тремя.

Как оформить это на письме правильно?

Например: – Что, чёрт..! Где, чёрт...(!!) Кто, чёрт...(!!!)

Оставлять ли многоточие полностью? Как это должно выглядеть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При сочетании знаков на первом месте всегда более "сильный", то есть вопросительный, затем восклицательный, затем - что там осталось от многоточия (потому что знаков подряд - не более трёх, это, к примеру, Велллер, отображая мат, может нарисовать несколько строк из *вопр-воскл*, - ну так то ж авторская воля).

> При сочетании вопросительного или восклицательного знака с многоточием
>   знаки эти ставятся на месте первой точки: *— Ну, что они там?..*
>   (Шукш.); — Сейчас зайдем к старику, так?*..* (Шукш.); *«Эх, елки
>   зеленые!..» — горько подумал он* (Шукш.).

Знак в скобках - отдельная статья, он уже как бы и не пунктуация.

Когда-то я задавала вопрос:

[**Знак в скобках после слова - (?) или (!) - требует пробела-отбивки?**](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/1732024-znak-v-skobkah-posle-slova--ili--trebuet-probela-otbivki.html)

> Так называемый сатирический восклицательный знак, заключённый в скобки
>   и поставленный после слова или высказывания, указывает на нелепость
>   или неверность сказанного. В профессиональной практике восклицательный
>   знак в скобках, напротив, используется для подтверждения крайне
>   необычного высказывания, как указание на намеренный, а не ошибочный
>   его характер (например, в медицине при выписке рецепта на дозировку,
>   превышающую предельно допустимую).

Ответ опытнейшего преподавателя русского языка:

> Чаще всего такие знаки, как восклицательный, вопросительный или
>   совместное расположение их, употребляются после высказываний или
>   внутри высказываний для выражения различных чувств пишущего к этому
>   высказыванию или даже к отдельному слову в высказывании, в цитате.
>   Обычно упомянутые знаки заключаются в скобки и от слова отделяются
>   пробелами.
>
> Почему не вплотную пишутся к предшествующему слову, как это делается в
>   предложениях восклицательных и вопросительных?
>
> Думаю, что они просто заменяют собой вполне определенные слова,
>   выражающие удивление, недоумение, иронию, возмущение и т.п. чувства,
>   то есть являются по своей сути вводными предложениями, а последние
>   могут заключаться в скобки и обязательно отделяться от других слов
>   пробелами.
>
> Например.
>
> *Прохожий поднял голову и увидел (!), что на него с крыши дома падает какой-то предмет.*
>
> Здесь (!) можно заменить выражением "О боже!" или "Какой ужас!" Этим
>   знаком привлекается внимание читателя к тому, что дальше речь пойдет о
>   чем-то необычном, удивительном.
>
> Или другой пример.
>
> *Студент утверждал, что это правило он прочитал в "Справочнике" Розенталя (?).*
>
> Знаком (?) выражается сомнение в том, что студент мог прочитать
>   правило в указанном справочнике, потому что нет такого правила там.
>   Знаком (?) заменяются слова "Неужели?" или "Вы уверены?"
>
> *Больная мать думала (?!), что сегодня сын наконец придет с работы вовремя.*
>
> Здесь и сомнение, и удивление высказывается, потому что такого никогда
>   не бывало и вряд ли случится, мама сама знает это.
>
> *Когда-нибудь (?) люди освоят и другие планеты.*
>
> Выражается сомнение, что это случится в обозримом будущем.

Черти из Вашего примера могут выглядеть так:

Что, чёрт!..

Где, чёрт?!.

Кто, чёрт?..

Предложения оборваны (потому и многоточие), пропущено (к примеру):

*Кто, чёрт (возьми), трогал мою чашку и сдвинул её?!*

Доставить ещё одну точку в конце - остаток убывшего многоточия - значит к интонации вопрошающего негодования добавить растерянности.

Comment: The Voice (coming nearer). Where the——! Who the——!! What the——!!! Это оригинал. Надо передать нарастающее возмущение. Где!.. Кто!!. Что!!! И на последнее тогда многоточия не хватает? Или можно добавить?

Comment: Скорее всего, нельзя.

Comment: Добавить отточие к имеющимся знакам нельзя. Но предложения всё же вопросительные с нотой крайнего возмущения. Поэтому так: *Где?!! Кто?!! Что?!!* Два клика после вопроса можно.

Comment: *Где, чёрт?!.* Так точно можно, Галина?

Comment: Тёмка, меня так учили - сто лет назад. И я слышу интонацию растерянности с этим обглодком отточия, а она точно присутствует. Правила найти не могу.

Comment: Просто я тоже встретил "?!." в книжке и хотел задать вопрос, можно ли так, но нашёл это. :)

Comment: Ой, какая ж я умная! аж жуть берёт! )))

Comment: Ахахахах)))))))