# Знак (вопросительный, восклицательный) в скобках при слове отбивается ли пробелом?

Tags: пунктуация

> Или вдруг, бывает, вынесет меня к бюсту доярки-ударницы, кстати
>   превосходному **(!)**, в крошечной деревне Черниговской области...

А может:

*Или вдруг, бывает, вынесет меня к бюсту доярки-ударницы (кстати, превосходному!) в крошечной деревне Черниговской области...*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Второй вариант мне больше нравится. С пробелами, по-моему, всё в порядке, но отдельно знак вопроса обычно обозначает эмоции ко всей фразе, а здесь ведь эмоции по поводу бюста, это эпитет эмоциональный, после него и ставим знак.

*Или вдруг, бывает, вынесет меня к бюсту доярки-ударницы (кстати, превосходному!) в крошечной деревне Черниговской области...*

Answer (score 1):

1. Точка, запятая, двоеточие, точка с запятой, многоточие, восклицательный и вопросительный знаки от предшествующих слов не отбиваются.
   Знаки препинания (а значит, и восклицательный знак) от скобок и кавычек также никогда не отбиваются.
   [Использование отбивок при верстке знаков и цифр](http://webserg.com/content/poligraf/?p=verst-otbiv)
2. Второй вариант оформления предложения предпочтительнее (вставка с восклицательным знаком смотрится весомее).
3. Вот [Ваш ответ](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/427152/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8) на этом сайте (мне добавить нечего): пробел ставится слева от открывающей скобки, справа — от закрывающей (если следом нет знака препинания).
   [**...превосходному (!)** — всё правильно.]

Comment: Риммуля, Вы о другом! У меня - о знаке в своих скобках!

Comment: Спасибо за дополнения: я не запомнила и потеряла ту цитату!